# Java SOAP-WS client horror

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, apache-axis

It's looking amazingly difficult to use any of the most used soap services framework (at least those I've tried) and come up with this kind of soap request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://bencws.foobar.com/doc/2008-01-01/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
    <soap:Header xmlns:foo="http://safe.foobar.com/doc/2007-01-01/" xmlns:oof="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <foo:AccessKeyId>0PKRFZMV7GRJ11N791R2</foo:AccessKeyId>
        <foo:Timestamp>2008-03-07T23:55:22.693Z</foo:Timestamp>
        <foo:Signature>someencodedstring</foo:Signature>
        <oof:Action>SomeAction</oof:Action>
        <oof:To>http://bencws.foobar.com</oof:To>
        <oof:MessageID>120493412293</oof:MessageID>
        <oof:ReplyTo>
            <oof:Address> http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</oof:Address>
        </oof:ReplyTo>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    ...
```

With [cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/) I started using [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html#UsingCXFwithmaven-MavenPlugin) to create classes stub from wsdl file.
But then the "standard" thingie did not allow to change soap:Header namespace or even add stuff inside the tag (unless you bend over backwards twice)

With [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) I used [WSDL2Java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#generating) and endend up with the same kind of troubles.

I've come up with what would look like formally "correct" soap requests but freaking *foobar* service won't accept them anyways unless my **soap:Envelope** and **soap:Header** don't look exactly like that.

Any help will be much appreciated. Should I try something else?
We're now at the point we're thinking to write the xml requests manually  which is something I'd avoid.

Comment: Which version SOAP use _foobar_ service? 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: Yeah, I also had trouble with cxf and soap Headers. It is possible, but feels like its buried so weirdly, you're not supposed to find it. Still, I would prefer cxf over axis2..maybe thats something personal though. But why would you want to change the soap namespace? I mean.. do you want to use soap or not?

Comment: seriously at this point i don't even know! they just told me it has to be like that.

Comment: With respect, if you have been able to produce a message that has elements with the right local names and namespace URIs but the service won't accept them unless you use specific prefixes, etc. then I'm afraid it's the _service_ that is broken, not the client...

Comment: @Ian Roberts i agree. what can i say... let's just say foobar is one of the top tech corporation rigth now :)

Answer (score 0):

With CXF, getting the namespaces declared onto the soap:Envelope is relatively easy. You can provide a Map of namespace -> prefix to the client via a request property:

```
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put("soap.env.ns.map", map);
```

Thus, if you can have the foo and oof namespaces declared there, you could do that.   Adding them onto the soap:Header is definitely not an easy thing to do.  :-(