# Java SOAP Client: WS-A and WS-S problems with CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf, soap-client, ws-security, ws-addressing

I'm trying to consume a SOAP webservice that expects WS-Security and WS-Adressing headers as SOAPHeaders. Similar to [Java SOAP-WS client horror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027354/java-soap-ws-client-horror) I was not able to get all these headers in my request.

I'm using CXF and have generated a webservice stub using the cxf-codegen plugin. I tried to add the WSS headers using WSSA4J interceptors (based on the cxf documentation [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)):

```java
    //WS-Security
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
    Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    // Specify our username
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, user.getUsername());
    // Password type : plain text
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    outProps.put("password", user.getPassword());
    //Add the interceptor
    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

But the request does not contain any WS-Security headers.

I have the same problem adding WS-A headers. Based on [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html) I wanted to add a < To > and < ReplyTo > tag:

```java
    //WS-A
    Map<String, Object> reqCtx = client.getRequestContext();

    AddressingProperties addrProperties = new AddressingProperties();
    EndpointReferenceType endpointRef = new EndpointReferenceType();
    AttributedURIType address = new AttributedURIType();
    address.setValue("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");
    endpointRef.setAddress(address);

    ReferenceParametersType refParams = new ReferenceParametersType();
    refParams.getAny().add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("ServiceGroupId"), String.class, sessionId));
    endpointRef.setReferenceParameters(refParams);
    addrProperties.setReplyTo(endpointRef);


    endpointRef = new EndpointReferenceType();
    address.setValue(endpointUrl);
    endpointRef.setAddress(address);
    addrProperties.setTo(endpointRef);

    reqCtx.put("javax.xml.ws.addressing.context", addrProperties);
```

I expected something like this:

```xml
<h:ReplyTo xmlns:h="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
<Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
<ReferenceParameters>
    <ServiceGroupId>urn:uuid:8f27332c08854fb09989b2d</ServiceGroupId>
</ReferenceParameters>
</h:ReplyTo>
<h:To xmlns:h="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
    http://...
</h:To>
```

But again, there was nothing in my SOAP request. What am I missing/doing wrong?

At this point I would also be happy if I could modify the SOAP headers directly and add them by hand. Can I modify the headers before the message is sent using an interceptor?

I'm using CXF 3.1.2, wss4j 2.1.2, Java 1.8 and Spring Boot 1.2.5.

Thank you!